# Conditional probability of cards

Tags: probability

> We have a uniformly random permutation of a deck of 52 cards.
>   What is the probability that the first card is an Ace, given that the bottom card is the Ace of spades? Pr(A|B)

**My Thoughts:**
So, what I have so far is that the Pr(A) = 4/52, and Pr(B) = 1/52.
I am not sure if I am correct in thinking that after we remove one of the four aces the ace of spades to be exact and put it at the bottom of the deck that the probability of the first card being an ace is now only 3/51. Is this idea correct? I would really appreciate if someone could lead me in the right direction of how to go about solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint:*  once you know that the bottom card is the Ace of Spades, there are $51$ cards remaining, $3$ of which are Aces.

Comment: Thanks, Sammy. I thought that was it, but just had to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[A|B]
 &= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}
  = \frac{\mathbb{P}[\text{ace on top AND ace of spades on the bottom}]}
         {\mathbb{P}[\text{ace of spades on the bottom}]} \\
 &= \frac{3/51 \times 1/52}{1/52}
  = \frac{3}{51} = \frac{1}{17}.
\end{split}$$